# K nearest neighbor VS Kernel density estimation (Parzen window)

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-smoothing, k-nearest-neighbour

I appreciate it if anyone could explain to me the advantages and disadvantages of knn and parzen relative to each other.

Comment: What do you mean by knn and parzen? Are these function names in R or something?